# Non isomorphic graphs with equal cycle matrices

Tags: graph-theory

everyone.
I have solved a following problem, the solution seems too simple, so I am suspicious, that I am making a mistake. Would be very greateful, if someone cheked the solution.

So, the problem : do there exist two simple, non isomorphic graphs, which cycle matrices are equal and every edge is contained in some cycle.

The solution : let two graphs be $G_1$ and $G_2$. Their corresponding cycle matrices are $C_1$ and $C_2$. Since they are aqual, let $C_1 = C_2 = C$. Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be icidence matrices of $G_1$ and $G_2$. From theory it is known that $C \cdot A_1^T = 0$ and $C \cdot A_2^T = 0$. But, then $C \cdot A_1^T = C \cdot A_2^T$ and $A_1^T = A_2^T$ and $A_1 = A_2$. But this means that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic. So the answer is no, such graphs do not exist.

Edit : since all matrices contain only values ${0,1}$, multiplication is done in the way, that $0 \cdot 0 = 0$, $1 \cdot 0 = 0$, $0 \cdot 1 = 0$ and $1 \cdot 1 = 1$

About the cycle matrix. Let the graph $G$ have $m$ edges and let $q$ be the number of different cycles in $G$. The cycle matrix $B = [b_{ij}]_{q \times m}$ of $G$ is $(1,0)$ matrix of order $q \times m$ with $b_{ij} = 1$ if the $i$th cycle includes $j$th edge and $b_{ij} = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: First line should be "Hallo, everyone". I have written that way dont know why it doesnt display as it should.

Comment: What is the cycle matrix?

Comment: I edited my question with definition of cycle matrix.

Comment: Title says "isomorphic," body asks for "non-isomorphic". Please edit one or the other.

Comment: In your argument, you cancel the matrix $C$ from both sides --- but since your multiplication has $1\cdot0=0$, this would not seem to be justified.

Comment: If $G_1$ is a cycle of length 3, and $G_2$ is a cycle of length 3 together with a 4th vertex (either isolated, or adjacent to one of the vertices in the 3-cycle), then the graphs have the same cycle matrix, but are not isomorphic, right?

Comment: Yes, seems like the case here would be $G_1$ - cycle of length $3$ and $G_2$, cycle of length $3$ and a $4$th vertex isolated (but not adjecent to one of other vertices, since it is said, that every edge must be in at least one cycle, thus, in this case cycle matrices would not be equal). Thanks.

Comment: I got my mistake in the solution. Since $C \cdot A_1^T = 0$ and $C \cdot A_2^T = 0$ and zeros are not zeros, but zero - matrices, i can't write $C \cdot A_1^T = C \cdot A_2^T$ since these zero - matrices might have different dimensions and thus not be equal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I have the right definition of cycle --- I'm assuming that something like abcadea (where the letters stand for vertices) doesn't count as a cycle, since it decomposes into two cycles, abca and adea. If I have it right, then there are connected counter-examples. Let $G_1$ be three triangles sharing a single vertex. Let $G_2$ also consist of three triangles, with the 1st and 2nd having one common vertex, the 2nd and 3rd having a different common vertex. Each graph has 9 edges forming 3 cycles, and the same cycle matrix $$\pmatrix{1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\cr0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0\cr0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\cr}$$ but the graphs are clearly not isomorphic, as only $G_1$ has a vertex of degree 6.